# Posistioning the close button on Lightbox

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, lightbox

I have added the plugin 'Responsive Lightbox Lite' to my Wordpress site and it is working a treat.

However I would like the close icon to be in the lightbox (top right) rather than displaying at the top right of the page.

So if you go to the following page you can see example of it working:

http://weaveapps.com/shop/wordpress-plugins/responsive-lightbox-lite/

Click on any of the images in the image gallery.

I can see the following css positions it:

```
.nivo-lightbox-close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2%;
    top: 2%;
}
```

and the structure is generated here:

```
<div class="nivo-lightbox-wrap">
<a class="nivo-lightbox-close" title="Close" href="#">Close</a>
```

So I can see they are separate from each other. If it helps here is the .php file:

```
class Responsive_Lightbox_Lite {

    //default settings
    private $defaults = array(
    'settings' => array(
        'script' => 'nivo_lightbox',
        'selector' => 'lightbox',
        'galleries' => true,
        'videos' => true,
        'image_links' => true,
        'images_as_gallery' => false,
        'deactivation_delete' => false,
        'loading_place' => 'header',
        'enable_custom_events' => false,
        'custom_events' => 'ajaxComplete'
    ),
    'version' => '1.0.0'
);
    private $options = array();
    private $tabs = array();
    private $gallery_no = 0;

    public function __construct() {

        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array(&$this, 'wa_rll_activation'));
        register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, array(&$this, 'wa_rll_deactivation'));

        //Add admin option
        add_action('admin_menu', array(&$this, 'admin_menu_options'));
        add_action('admin_init', array(&$this, 'register_settings'));

        //add text domain for localization
        add_action('plugins_loaded', array(&$this, 'load_textdomain'));

        //load defaults
        add_action('plugins_loaded', array(&$this, 'load_defaults'));

        //update plugin version
        update_option('responsive_lightbox_lite_version', $this->defaults['version'], '', 'no');
        $this->options['settings'] = array_merge($this->defaults['settings'], (($array = get_option('responsive_lightbox_lite_settings')) === FALSE ? array() : $array));

        //insert js and css files
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'include_scripts'));
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'admin_include_scripts'));

        if($this->options['settings']['galleries'] === TRUE)
        add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', array(&$this, 'add_lightbox_selector_gallery'), 1000, 6);

        if($this->options['settings']['videos'] === TRUE)
        add_filter('the_content', array(&$this, 'add_lightbox_selector_videos')); 

        if($this->options['settings']['image_links'] === TRUE || $this->options['settings']['images_as_gallery'] === TRUE)
        add_filter('the_content', array(&$this, 'add_lightbox_selector_images_links'));
    }

    //activation hook
    public function wa_rll_activation() {
        add_option('responsive_lightbox_lite_settings', $this->defaults['settings'], '', 'no');
        add_option('responsive_lightbox_lite_version', $this->defaults['version'], '', 'no');
    }

    //deactivation hook
    public function wa_rll_deactivation($multi = FALSE)
    {

        $check = $this->options['settings']['deactivation_delete'];

        if($check === TRUE)
        {
            delete_option('responsive_lightbox_lite_settings');
            delete_option('responsive_lightbox_lite_version');
        }
    }

    /* Add lightbox selector for gallery */
    public function add_lightbox_selector_gallery($link, $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text)
    {
        $link = (preg_match('/<a.*? rel=("|\').*?("|\')>/', $link) === 1 ? preg_replace('/(<a.*? rel=(?:"|\').*?)((?:"|\').*?>)/', '$1 '.$this->options['settings']['selector'].'[gallery-'.$this->gallery_no.']'.'$2', $link) : preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 rel="'.$this->options['settings']['selector'].'[gallery-'.$this->gallery_no.']'.'">', $link));

        return (preg_match('/<a.*? href=("|\').*?("|\')>/', $link) === 1 ? preg_replace('/(<a.*? href=(?:"|\')).*?((?:"|\').*?>)/', '$1'.wp_get_attachment_url($id).'$2', $link) : preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($id).'">', $link));
    }

    /* add lightbox selectors for videos */
    public function add_lightbox_selector_videos($content)
    {
        preg_match_all('/<a(.*?)href=(?:\'|")((?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[a-z0-9_\-]+)|(vimeo\.com\/[0-9]{8,})))(?:\'|")(.*?)>/i', $content, $links);

        if(isset($links[0]))
        {
            foreach($links[0] as $id => $link)
            {
                if(preg_match('/<a.*?rel=(?:\'|")(.*?)(?:\'|").*?>/', $link, $result) === 1)
                {
                    if(isset($result[1]))
                    {
                        $new_rels = array();
                        $rels = explode(' ', $result[1]);

                        if(in_array($this->options['settings']['selector'], $rels, TRUE))
                        {
                            foreach($rels as $no => $rel)
                            {
                                if($rel !== $this->options['settings']['selector'])
                                    $new_rels[] = $rel;
                            }

                            $content = str_replace($link, preg_replace('/rel=(?:\'|")(.*?)(?:\'|")/', 'rel="'.(!empty($new_rel) ? simplode(' ', $new_rels).' ' : '').$this->options['settings']['selector'].'-video-'.$id.'"', $link), $content);
                        }
                        else
                            $content = str_replace($link, preg_replace('/rel=(?:\'|")(.*?)(?:\'|")/', 'rel="'.($result[1] !== '' ? $result[1].' ' : '').$this->options['settings']['selector'].'-video-'.$id.'"', $link), $content);
                    }
                }
                else if(preg_match('/<a(.*?)href=(?:\'|")((?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[a-z0-9_\-]+)))(?:\'|")(.*?)>/', $link, $result) === 1){
                    $content = str_replace($link, '<a'.$links[1][$id].'href="'.$links[2][$id].'"'.$links[6][$id].' rel="'.$this->options['settings']['selector'].'-video-'.$id.'" data-type="youtube">', $content);

                    }else if(preg_match('/<a(.*?)href=(?:\'|")((?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?((vimeo\.com\/[0-9]{8,})))(?:\'|")(.*?)>/', $link, $result) === 1){

                    $content = str_replace($link, '<a'.$links[1][$id].'href="'.$links[2][$id].'"'.$links[6][$id].' rel="'.$this->options['settings']['selector'].'-video-'.$id.'" data-type="vimeo">', $content);

                    }

            }
        }

        return $content;
    }

    /* add lightbox selectors for images links */
    public function add_lightbox_selector_images_links($content)
    {
        preg_match_all('/<a(.*?)href=(?:\'|")([^<]*?).(bmp|gif|jpeg|jpg|png)(?:\'|")(.*?)>/i', $content, $links);
        if(isset($links[0]))
        {
            if($this->options['settings']['images_as_gallery'] === TRUE)
                $rel_hash = '[gallery-'.wp_generate_password(4, FALSE, FALSE).']';
            foreach($links[0] as $id => $link)
            {
                if(preg_match('/<a.*?rel=(?:\'|")(.*?)(?:\'|").*?>/', $link, $result) === 1)
                {
                    if($this->options['settings']['images_as_gallery'] === TRUE)
                    {
                        $content = str_replace($link, preg_replace('/rel=(?:\'|")(.*?)(?:\'|")/', 'rel="'.$this->options['settings']['selector'].$rel_hash.'"'.($this->options['settings']['script'] === 'imagelightbox' ? ' data-imagelightbox="'.$id.'"' : ''), $link), $content);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(isset($result[1]))
                        {
                            $new_rels = array();
                            $rels = explode(' ', $result[1]);

                            if(in_array($this->options['settings']['selector'], $rels, TRUE))
                            {
                                foreach($rels as $no => $rel)
                                {
                                    if($rel !== $this->options['settings']['selector'])
                                        $new_rels[] = $rel;
                                }

                                $content = str_replace($link, preg_replace('/rel=(?:\'|")(.*?)(?:\'|")/', 'rel="'.(!empty($new_rels) ? implode(' ', $new_rels).' ' : '').$this->options['settings']['selector'].'-'.$id.'"'.($this->options['settings']['script'] === 'imagelightbox' ? ' data-imagelightbox="'.$id.'"' : ''), $link), $content);
                            }
                            else
                                $content = str_replace($link, preg_replace('/rel=(?:\'|")(.*?)(?:\'|")/', 'rel="'.($result[1] !== '' ? $result[1].' ' : '').$this->options['settings']['selector'].'-'.$id.'"'.($this->options['settings']['script'] === 'imagelightbox' ? ' data-imagelightbox="'.$id.'"' : ''), $link), $content);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                    $content = str_replace($link, '<a'.$links[1][$id].'href="'.$links[2][$id].'.'.$links[3][$id].'"'.$links[4][$id].' rel="'.$this->options['settings']['selector'].($this->options['settings']['images_as_gallery'] === TRUE ? $rel_hash : '-'.$id).'"'.($this->options['settings']['script'] === 'imagelightbox' ? ' data-imagelightbox="'.$id.'"' : '').'>', $content);
            }
        }
        return $content;
    }

    /* insert css files js files */
    public function include_scripts() { 

        $args = apply_filters('rll_lightbox_args', array(
            'script' => $this->options['settings']['script'],
            'selector' => $this->options['settings']['selector'],
            'custom_events' => ($this->options['settings']['enable_custom_events'] === TRUE ? ' '.$this->options['settings']['custom_events'] : '')
        ));

        if($args['script'] === 'nivo_lightbox'){

            wp_register_script('responsive-lightbox-nivo_lightbox',plugins_url('assets/nivo-lightbox/nivo-lightbox.min.js', __FILE__),array('jquery'),'',($this->options['settings']['loading_place'] === 'header' ? false : true));
            wp_enqueue_script('responsive-lightbox-nivo_lightbox');

            wp_register_style('responsive-lightbox-nivo_lightbox-css',plugins_url('assets/nivo-lightbox/nivo-lightbox.css', __FILE__));
            wp_enqueue_style('responsive-lightbox-nivo_lightbox-css');

                    wp_register_style('responsive-lightbox-nivo_lightbox-css-d',plugins_url('assets/nivo-lightbox/themes/default/default.css', __FILE__));
            wp_enqueue_style('responsive-lightbox-nivo_lightbox-css-d');

        }
            wp_register_script('responsive-lightbox-lite-script',plugins_url('assets/inc/script.js', __FILE__),array('jquery'),'',($this->options['settings']['loading_place'] === 'header' ? false : true));
            wp_enqueue_script('responsive-lightbox-lite-script');

            wp_localize_script('responsive-lightbox-lite-script','rllArgs',$args);
    }

    /* insert css files for admin area */
    public function admin_include_scripts() {
            wp_register_style('responsive-lightbox-lite-admin',plugins_url('assets/css/admin.css', __FILE__));
            wp_enqueue_style('responsive-lightbox-lite-admin');
    }

    public function admin_menu_options()
    {
        add_options_page(
            __('Responsive Lightbox Lite', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'),
            __('Responsive Lightbox Lite', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'),
            'manage_options',
            'responsive-lightbox-lite',
            array(&$this, 'options_page')
        );
    }

    /* register setting for plugins page */
    public function register_settings()
    {
        register_setting('responsive_lightbox_lite_settings', 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings', array(&$this, 'validate_options'));
        //general settings
        add_settings_section('responsive_lightbox_lite_settings', __('', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'), '', 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings');
        add_settings_field('rll_galleries', __('Galleries', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'), array(&$this, 'rll_galleries'), 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings', 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings');
        add_settings_field('rll_videos', __('Video links', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'), array(&$this, 'rll_videos'), 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings', 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings');
        add_settings_field('rll_image_links', __('Image links', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'), array(&$this, 'rll_image_links'), 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings', 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings');
        add_settings_field('rll_enable_custom_events', __('Custom events', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'), array(&$this, 'rll_enable_custom_events'), 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings', 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings');
        add_settings_field('rll_loading_place', __('Loading place', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'), array(&$this, 'rll_loading_place'), 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings', 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings');
        add_settings_field('rll_deactivation_delete', __('Deactivation', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'), array(&$this, 'rll_deactivation_delete'), 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings', 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings');
    }




    public function rll_enable_custom_events()
    {
        echo '
        <div id="rll_enable_custom_events" class="wplikebtns">';

        foreach($this->choices as $val => $trans)
        {
            $val = esc_attr($val);

            echo '
            <input id="rll-enable-custom-events-'.$val.'" type="radio" name="responsive_lightbox_settings[enable_custom_events]" value="'.$val.'" '.checked(($val === 'yes' ? true : false), $this->options['settings']['enable_custom_events'], false).' />
            <label for="rll-enable-custom-events-'.$val.'">'.esc_html($trans).'</label>';
        }

        echo '
            <p class="description">'.__('Enable triggering lightbox on custom jquery events.', 'responsive-lightbox').'</p>
            <div id="rll_custom_events"'.($this->options['settings']['enable_custom_events'] === false ? ' style="display: none;"' : '').'>
                <input type="text" name="responsive_lightbox_settings[custom_events]" value="'.esc_attr($this->options['settings']['custom_events']).'" />
                <p class="description">'.__('Enter a space separated list of events.', 'responsive-lightbox').'</p>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }

    public function rll_loading_place()
    {
        echo '
        <div id="rll_loading_place" class="wplikebtns">';

        foreach($this->loading_places as $val => $trans)
        {
            $val = esc_attr($val);

            echo '
            <input id="rll-loading-place-'.$val.'" type="radio" name="responsive_lightbox_lite_settings[loading_place]" value="'.$val.'" '.checked($val, $this->options['settings']['loading_place'], false).' />
            <label for="rll-loading-place-'.$val.'">'.esc_html($trans).'</label>';
        }

        echo '
            <p class="description">'.__('Select where all the lightbox scripts should be placed.', 'responsive-lightbox').'</p>
        </div>';
    }

    public function rll_galleries()
    {
        echo '
        <div id="rll_galleries" class="wplikebtns">';

        foreach($this->choices as $val => $trans)
        {
            echo '
            <input id="rll-galleries-'.$val.'" type="radio" name="responsive_lightbox_lite_settings[galleries]" value="'.esc_attr($val).'" '.checked(($val === 'yes' ? TRUE : FALSE), $this->options['settings']['galleries'], FALSE).' />
            <label for="rll-galleries-'.$val.'">'.$trans.'</label>';
        }

        echo '
            <p class="description">'.__('Add lightbox to WordPress image galleries by default.', 'responsive-lightbox').'</p>
        </div>';
    }

    public function rll_videos()
    {
        echo '
        <div id="rll_videos" class="wplikebtns">';

        foreach($this->choices as $val => $trans)
        {
            echo '
            <input id="rll-videos-'.$val.'" type="radio" name="responsive_lightbox_lite_settings[videos]" value="'.esc_attr($val).'" '.checked(($val === 'yes' ? TRUE : FALSE), $this->options['settings']['videos'], FALSE).' />
            <label for="rll-videos-'.$val.'">'.$trans.'</label>';
        }

        echo '
            <p class="description">'.__('Add lightbox to YouTube and Vimeo video links by default.', 'responsive-lightbox').'</p>
        </div>';
    }

    public function rll_image_links()
    {
        echo '
        <div id="rll_image_links" class="wplikebtns">';

        foreach($this->choices as $val => $trans)
        {
            echo '
            <input id="rll-image-links-'.$val.'" type="radio" name="responsive_lightbox_lite_settings[image_links]" value="'.esc_attr($val).'" '.checked(($val === 'yes' ? TRUE : FALSE), $this->options['settings']['image_links'], FALSE).' />
            <label for="rll-image-links-'.$val.'">'.$trans.'</label>';
        }

        echo '
            <p class="description">'.__('Add lightbox to WordPress image links by default.', 'responsive-lightbox').'</p>
        </div>';
    }

    public function rll_images_as_gallery()
    {
        echo '
        <div id="rll_images_as_gallery" class="wplikebtns">';

        foreach($this->choices as $val => $trans)
        {
            echo '
            <input id="rll-images-as-gallery-'.$val.'" type="radio" name="responsive_lightbox_lite_settings[images_as_gallery]" value="'.esc_attr($val).'" '.checked(($val === 'yes' ? TRUE : FALSE), $this->options['settings']['images_as_gallery'], FALSE).' />
            <label for="rll-images-as-gallery-'.$val.'">'.$trans.'</label>';
        }

        echo '
            <p class="description">'.__('Display single post images as a gallery.', 'responsive-lightbox').'</p>
        </div>';
    }

    public function rll_deactivation_delete()
    {
        echo '
        <div id="rll_deactivation_delete" class="wplikebtns">';

        foreach($this->choices as $val => $trans)
        {
            echo '
            <input id="rll-deactivation-delete-'.$val.'" type="radio" name="responsive_lightbox_lite_settings[deactivation_delete]" value="'.esc_attr($val).'" '.checked(($val === 'yes' ? TRUE : FALSE), $this->options['settings']['deactivation_delete'], FALSE).' />
            <label for="rll-deactivation-delete-'.$val.'">'.$trans.'</label>';
        }

        echo '
            <p class="description">'.__('Delete settings on plugin deactivation.', 'responsive-lightbox').'</p>
        </div>';
    }

    public function options_page()
    {
        $tab_key = (isset($_GET['tab']) ? $_GET['tab'] : 'general-settings');

        echo '<div class="wrap">'.screen_icon().'
            <h2>'.__('Responsive Lightbox Lite', 'responsive-lightbox-lite').'</h2>
            <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">';

        foreach($this->tabs as $key => $name) {
            echo '
            <a class="nav-tab '.($tab_key == $key ? 'nav-tab-active' : '').'" href="'.esc_url(admin_url('options-general.php?page=responsive-lightbox-lite&tab='.$key)).'">'.$name['name'].'</a>';
        }

        echo '
            </h2>
            <div class="responsive-lightbox-settings">
                <div class="wa-credits">
                    <h3 class="hndle">'.__('Responsive Lightbox Lite', 'responsive-lightbox').'</h3>
                    <div class="inside">
                        <p class="inner">'.__('Plugin URI: ', 'responsive-lightbox').' <a href="http://weaveapps.com/shop/wordpress-plugins/responsive-lightbox-lite/" target="_blank" title="'.__('Plugin URL', 'responsive-lightbox-lite').'">'.__('Weave Apps', 'responsive-lightbox-lite').'</a></p>
                    </p> 
                    <hr />
                    <h4 class="inner">'.__('Do you like this plugin?', 'responsive-lightbox').'</h4>
                    <p class="inner">'.__('Please, ', 'wa-wps-txt').'<a href="http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/responsive-lightbox-lite" target="_blank" title="'.__('rate it', 'wa-wps-txt').'">'.__('rate it', 'wa-wps-txt').'</a> '.__('on WordPress.org', 'wa-wps-txt').'<br />                     
                        <hr />
                    <div style="width:auto; margin:auto; text-align:center;"><a href="http://weaveapps.com/shop/wordpress-plugins/responsive-lightbox-wordpress-plugin/" target="_blank"><img width="270" height="70" src="'.plugins_url('assets/images/pro.png',__FILE__).'"/></a></div>

                    </div>
                </div><form action="options.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="script_r" value="'.esc_attr($this->options['settings']['script']).'" />';

        wp_nonce_field('update-options');
        settings_fields($this->tabs[$tab_key]['key']);
        do_settings_sections($this->tabs[$tab_key]['key']);

        echo '<p class="submit">';
        submit_button('', 'primary', $this->tabs[$tab_key]['submit'], FALSE);
        echo ' ';
        echo submit_button(__('Reset to defaults', 'responsive-lightbox'), 'secondary', $this->tabs[$tab_key]['reset'], FALSE);
        echo '</p></form></div><div class="clear"></div></div>';
    }

    public function load_defaults()
    {

        $this->choices = array(
            'yes' => __('Enable', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'),
            'no' => __('Disable', 'responsive-lightbox-lite')
        );

        $this->loading_places = array(
            'header' => __('Header', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'),
            'footer' => __('Footer', 'responsive-lightbox-lite')
        );

        $this->tabs = array(
            'general-settings' => array(
                'name' => __('General settings', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'),
                'key' => 'responsive_lightbox_lite_settings',
                'submit' => 'save_rll_settings',
                'reset' => 'reset_rll_settings',
            )
        );
    }

    /* load text domain for localization */
    public function load_textdomain()
    {
        load_plugin_textdomain('responsive-lightbox-lite', FALSE, dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).'/languages/');
    }

    /* validate options and register settings */
    public function validate_options($input)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['save_rll_settings']))
        {

            // selector
            $input['selector'] = sanitize_text_field(isset($input['selector']) && $input['selector'] !== '' ? $input['selector'] : $this->defaults['settings']['selector']);

            // loading place
            $input['loading_place'] = (isset($input['loading_place'], $this->loading_places[$input['loading_place']]) ? $input['loading_place'] : $this->defaults['settings']['loading_place']);

            // enable custom events
            $input['enable_custom_events'] = (isset($input['enable_custom_events'], $this->choices[$input['enable_custom_events']]) ? ($input['enable_custom_events'] === 'yes' ? true : false) : $this->defaults['settings']['enable_custom_events']);

            // custom events
            if($input['enable_custom_events'] === true)
            {
                $input['custom_events'] = sanitize_text_field(isset($input['custom_events']) && $input['custom_events'] !== '' ? $input['custom_events'] : $this->defaults['settings']['custom_events']);
            }

            // checkboxes
            $input['galleries'] = (isset($input['galleries'], $this->choices[$input['galleries']]) ? ($input['galleries'] === 'yes' ? true : false) : $this->defaults['settings']['galleries']);
            $input['videos'] = (isset($input['videos'], $this->choices[$input['videos']]) ? ($input['videos'] === 'yes' ? true : false) : $this->defaults['settings']['videos']);
            $input['image_links'] = (isset($input['image_links'], $this->choices[$input['image_links']]) ? ($input['image_links'] === 'yes' ? true : false) : $this->defaults['settings']['image_links']);
            $input['images_as_gallery'] = (isset($input['images_as_gallery'], $this->choices[$input['images_as_gallery']]) ? ($input['images_as_gallery'] === 'yes' ? true : false) : $this->defaults['settings']['images_as_gallery']);
            $input['deactivation_delete'] = (isset($input['deactivation_delete'], $this->choices[$input['deactivation_delete']]) ? ($input['deactivation_delete'] === 'yes' ? true : false) : $this->defaults['settings']['deactivation_delete']);


        }elseif(isset($_POST['reset_rll_settings']))
        {
            $input = $this->defaults['settings'];

            add_settings_error('reset_general_settings', 'general_reset', __('Settings restored to defaults.', 'responsive-lightbox-lite'), 'updated');
        }

        return $input;
    }
}
$responsive_lightbox = new Responsive_Lightbox_Lite();
```

If anybody wants the .js deatils just let me know

UPDATE I have seen this strip of code in the .js file:

```
constructLightbox: function(){
            if($('.nivo-lightbox-overlay').length) return $('.nivo-lightbox-overlay');

            var overlay = $('<div>', { 'class': 'nivo-lightbox-overlay nivo-lightbox-theme-'+ this.options.theme +' nivo-lightbox-effect-'+ this.options.effect });
            var wrap = $('<div>', { 'class': 'nivo-lightbox-wrap' });
            var content = $('<div>', { 'class': 'nivo-lightbox-content' });
            var nav = $('<a href="#" class="nivo-lightbox-nav nivo-lightbox-prev">Previous</a><a href="#" class="nivo-lightbox-nav nivo-lightbox-next">Next</a>');
            var close = $('<a href="#" class="nivo-lightbox-close" title="Close">Close</a>');
            var title = $('<div>', { 'class': 'nivo-lightbox-title-wrap' });

            var isMSIE = /*@cc_on!@*/0;
            if(isMSIE) overlay.addClass('nivo-lightbox-ie');

            wrap.append(content);
            wrap.append(title);
            overlay.append(wrap);
            overlay.append(nav);
            overlay.append(close);
            $('body').append(overlay);
```

Is this what I need to update so the close link is witin the lightbox div??

Answer (score 0):

Strange placement of the icon, as it should normally be on the same div that holds the image, something like what Fancybox http://fancybox.net/ does.

In your case, the  is completely independent of the wrap for your image, hence the location wont match exactly the place in the corner you want it to be.

Comment: Hmmm I see what you mean - I am not sure how to move the close link into the div, however I have found where it generates it in the .js which I have added to the bottom of my question

Comment: Closest solution then would be to append the close to the wrap object: wrap.append(close);  Unfortunately thats as close as you will get with the structure that is generated without having to modify the actual NIVO javascript.

Comment: Hmmmm interesting - how would I put the 'object: wrap.append(close);' in so I can see how it looks?

Comment: In the end I spoke to the person who made it, by paying for Pro (only $14) they would tweek the code to make it look just how I wanted it - which is great!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding 'position:relative' to the nivo-lightbox-wrap class?

Comment: Thank you - I have yes but it put the whole lightbox into the top right hand corner of the screen, I have added some .js code at the end of my question that may help everyone :-)